# How to populate a Table in View with Json results on click of button MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an HTML form with a dropdown, two text boxes and a cancel, submit buttons. During the page load i am loading the dropdown with values from external source. When clicking of the Submit button, i am making a service call and get result as JSON and that data is used to populate the table. Now the table is a static one. Soon the table structure will change and contents of it including the text has to be dynamically populated. This should happen on the submit button click. How do i achieve this?

```
@model UI.ViewModels.CViewModel
<div id="mainDiv">
     @using (Html.BeginForm("Submit","Test",FormMethod.Post))
     {
    <div id="entryDiv">
            <table id="entryTable"> 
        <tr>
                    <td class="tdDescription">Select an  Plan </td>
                    <td class="tdAmount" id="tdPlan">
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(c => Model.SelectedPlan, Model.InstallmentPlans, new { @class = "ddlPlanType", @id = "InstallmentPlans" })<br />
             <div id="divSelectPlan" class="errorText hideElement">Please select a plan</div>
            </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
            <td class="tdDescription">Enter an Item Price </td>
                    <td class="tdAmount" id="tdItemPrice"><span>$ </span>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ItemPrice, new { @class = "tdText", required = "required" })<br />
            </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="tdDescription">Enter a Payment </td>
                    <td class="tdAmount" id="tdPayment"><span>$ </span>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Payment, new { @class = "tdText", required = "required" })<br />
            </td>
                </tr>           
            </table>
       <div id="submitDiv">
            <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "DPPC")"><span><span id="spanClear" class="spanButton">Clear</span></span></a>
            <input type="submit" id="spanSubmit" value="Submit" class="spanSubmitButton" />
       </div>          
     </div>
     <div id="ResultsDivWrapper" class="hideElement">
            <div id="resultsDiv"><span id="spnReturnedType"></span> Plan
                <table id="tblResults">
                    <tr>
                        <td id="tdResultData1">Test Price</td>
                        <td id="tdResultTestPrice"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td id="tdResultDP">DP</td>
                        <td id="tdResultDPS"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td id="tdResultFM">FM</td>
                        <td id="tdResultFMS"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td id="tdResultMP">MP</td>
                        <td id="tdResultMPS"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td id="tdResultFirstPayment">FP</td>
                        <td id="tdResultFPS"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td id="tdResultDD">DD</td>
                        <td id="tdResultDDS"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

script call

```
$("#spanSubmit").click(function () {

        var model = {
            Plans: '',
            SelectedPlan: seleted,
            EPrice: $("#ItemPrice").val(),
            DownPayment: $("#Payment").val()
        };
        Process("/DPPC/Submit", "POST", JSON.stringify(model), "json", "application/json;charset=utf-8", logError, InvokeSuccess);
    }
    return false;
});

function Process(url,type,data,datatype,contenttype,errorCallback,successCallback) {
    $.ajax({ url: url, type: type, data: data, dataType: datatype, contentType: contenttype, error: errorCallback, success: successCallback, async: true, processData: false });
}

function InvokeSuccess(result) {

    $("#tdResultTestPrice").html("$" + $("#ItemPrice").val());
    $("#tdResultDPS").html("$" + $("#Payment").val());
    $("#tdResultFMS").html("$" + result.FM.toFixed(2));
    $("#tdResultMPS").html("$" + result.MP.toFixed(2));
    $("#tdResultFPS").html("$" + result.FP.toFixed(2));

}

public class PPCResponse
    {
        public double FM { get; set; }
        public double MP { get; set; }
        public double FP{ get; set; }
        public double DD { get; set; }
    ..............
    }

[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SubmitCViewModel cModel)
        {
            try
            {
                PPCResponse response = cRepository.GetInstallmentDetails(cModel.SelectedPlan,cModel.ItemPrice,cModel.DP);
                return Json(response, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                int errorCode = LogUtility.ErrorLogCustom(ex.ToString());
                Response.StatusCode = 500;
                return Json(new { Error = errorCode.ToString() });
            }
        }
```

Now content of the table has to be generated dynamically. I have to change my PPCResponse to have some Dictionary and bind result back to the table. Problem is how do create the table rows runtime and bind the records?

Tutu

Comment: check the `foreach` syntax in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929538/c-sharp-mvc3-razor-alternating-items-in-a-foreach-list

Answer (score 0):

Put the table into a partial view and use an ajax call to refresh the partial view based on the data passed

```
$('.btnSubmit').on('click', function(){
    $.ajax({
       url: "@(Url.Action("Action", "Controller"),
        type: "POST",
        data: { data1: 'data1', data2: 'data2' } 
        cache: false,
        async: true,
        success: function (result) {
            $(".Content").html(result);
        }
    });
});
```

and then in your controller

```
public PartialViewResult Action(string data1, string data2){
    var model = (query database);
    return PartialView("_TablePartial", model);
}
```

then put a div around your table where the result will be put with a class on Content (or whatever you want to call it)
Hopefully this helps