# ajax post to httpost action method with no refresh special load in

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

First off I must say I have a bit of a brain teaser here. I may be a bit new to ASP.Net MVC4 but I have never attempted anything like this. The end goal is a type of tree view for partial pages in a standard page. Right now I am trying to use ajax to load a partial in a div while passing the users selection to the next view(it will than be used to narrow that pages results).

```
<div>
    <div>
        <form id="myForm" action="ScheduleZone" method="post">
            <table class="table">
                <tr>
                    <th>Store
                    </th>
                </tr>
                @foreach (ACS.Models.Tree rate in TempML.Tree)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => rate.Store)@Html.ActionLink("+", "            ScheduleZone", rate, new { @class = "g" })
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="div" id="mainDiv">
    </div>
    <div class="div" id="Zone">
    </div>
    <div class="div" id="Sell">
    </div>
    <div class="div" id="Meh">
    </div>
    <div class="div" id="Sk">
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".g").click(function () {
        $("#mainDiv").load("/Home/Zone");
    });
</script>
```

I can't seem to call the page in the div after calling the http post action. It returns just the partial view not in the div.

```
    public ActionResult Zone(CommisionsTree tree)
    {
        string banner = "2";
        CommissionDAO dao = new CommissionDAO();
        DataSet commissionInfo = dao.GetCommissionRates(tree, banner);
        ModelList ml = new ModelList();
        foreach (DataTable Table in commissionInfo.Tables)
        {
            foreach (DataRow row in Table.Rows)
            {
                Tree commTree = new Tree();
                commTree.Banner = Convert.ToInt32(banner);
                commTree.Store = tree.Store;
                foreach (DataColumn column in Table.Columns)
                {
                    switch (column.ColumnName)
                    {
                        case "SCHED_ZONE":
                            commTree.ScheduleZone = row[column].ToString();
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
                ml.CommissionTree.Add(commTree);
            }
            TempData["TempModelList"] = ml;
        }
        return  PartialView(ml);
    }
```

Comment: see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19391736/how-to-populate-a-table-in-view-with-json-results-on-click-of-button-mvc/19392340#19392340

Comment: You should change your `$("#mainDiv").load("/Home/Zone");` to `$("#mainDiv").load('@Url.Action("Zone", "Home")');`

Comment: I have switched  to the @url.Aaction() but to no avail i think everyone is really close. this would be allot easier if i wasnt so new.

Comment: Changing to the UrlHelper is a better practice, but it doesn't change the mecanic of this problem

Comment: Show the code from your controller action that is returning the partial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace your link + javascript with an AjaxLink

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("+", "Zone", "Home", new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "GET", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "mainDiv" }, htmlAttributes: new { @class="someClasses", id = "anId"})
```

In this case, the reason why it's following link after it's loading it's because your need to return false at the end of your javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".g").click(function () {
        $("#mainDiv").load("/Home/Zone");
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: That seems to act close to what i want i goes to the method but it doesnt load a view in the div.

Comment: Using the AjaxHelper, you can change the InsertionMode to modify how/where the div will be created/modified

Comment: i commented out all the javascript and used the ajax link and it goes to method and doesnt resubmit the page (which is good) but i cant quite get the partial to load into the div.

Comment: i cant help but think the problem is how i return the view (return partialView(ml))

Comment: is there a way to assign an class to the ajax link so it will use the js

Comment: Could you post your HomeController Zone Method?

Comment: I've updated my anwser to show adding a class/id to the `Ajax.ActionLink`

Comment: after adding the class and id it no longer runs the method.

Comment: The controller looks good. When you say "cant quite get the partial to load into the div". Where is the partialview loading? Using firebug, is the html returned correctly?

Comment: much to my dismay i have no access to fire bug my only means of debugging are visual studios